# Использование IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb, javascript

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь разобраться с **`IndexedDB`** под `Google Chrome` для хранения данных на стороне клиента больше 5 мб. Возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Где найти адекватное описание `IndexedDB` с рабочими примерами? [www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) по этой ссылке не нашел интересующей инфы(((
2. Какой максимальный объем можно хранить в `IndexedDB` ?
3. Как большой объем данных влияет на производительность браузера?
4. Как удалять/добавлять записи?
5. Для чего используется номер версии `(setVersion)` ???

Кое-что удалось нарыть на [www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/):

```
var request =  indexedDB.open("library");
request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
    var db = request.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore("books", {keyPath: "isbn"});
    var titleIndex = store.createIndex("by_title", "title", {unique: true});
    var authorIndex = store.createIndex("by_author", "author");
    for (var i=0; i<5000; i++) {
        store.put({title: i, author: i, isbn: i});
    }
};
request.onsuccess = function() {
    db = request.result;
};
```

Почему этот код создает только 50 записей, а не 5000?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB
https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#temporary

Comment: благодарю за ссылки, попробовал navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(50*1024*1024) только все равно 50 элементов создает и не больше.....

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=IndexedDB%2FIDBObjectStore#put()> put()

> Returns an **IDBRequest** object, and, in a **separate thread**, creates a structured clone of the value, and stores the cloned value in the object store. If the record is successfully stored, then a success event is fired on the returned request object with the result set to the key for the stored record, and transaction set to the transaction in which this object store is opened.

> The put method is an update or insert method. See also the add() metho

Comment: операция то асинхронная, надо  бы как-то или подождать каждую или хотя-бы все, а так как-то странно получается. [читаем здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=IndexedDB%2FIDBRequest)

и ещё - может вместо put add ?

Comment: Все разобрался. Это я тупанул. Я проверял записи дб через панель разработчика хрома, а там в пределах одной страницы показывает лишь 50 элементов, надо было листать страницы и тогда видно остальные записи. Извиняюсь, за свою невнимательность

Comment: Ну как разобрались с IndexedDB?

Answer (score 3):

Записей добавилось 5000, просто отображаются они 50 записей, с верху таблицы есть навигация по группам записей (треугольники влево и вправо) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]